# Get Doom's Items Found, Monster Kills, and Secrets Found stats before Level complete?

Tags: doom

Is there a way to get the level end stats while still playing the level in Doom 1 (1993)?

We are using Zandronum through DoomSeeker and want to find every secret before finishing the level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GZDoom and Zandronum;

To show the level stats, go to Options -> HUD Options -> Alternative HUD

Check Enable alternative HUD, and turn on Show item count. The rest are already on. Then when playing the game zoom out with the equal key until just the base stats are shown. The stats should be on the bottom left of the screen. K is Kills, I is Items, and S is secrets.